# systemd-journald Doesn't start at all

Tags: systemd, journald, journalctl

After deleting my `/var/log/journal` by accident, I am unable to recover from the consequences. `systemd-journald` keeps failing over and over again every time I try to start it. when I run:

```
$ journalctl --verify
PASS: /run/log/journal/system.journal
```

which doesn't bring me one step closer to solve it because `/run/log/journal/system.journal` is created when I run `/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-journald` directly, which on it self outputs

```
$ /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-journald
Failed to open runtime journal: Invalid argument
```

Things I have already tried:

1. cleaning `/var/log/journal and`/run/log/journal`.
2. copying `/var/log/journal` from another machine to both paths, running `journalctl --verify` to check them, and once again with `--file` flag.
3. changing Storage setting in `/etc/systemd/journald.conf` to `Storage=volatile` just to disable `/var/log/journald`.
4. Rebooting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After renaming the hostname, deleting & recreating `/etc/machine-id` by running `systemd-machine-id-setup` and rebooting to apply these, systemd-journald came back to life!

Comment: I deleted and recreated `/etc/machine-id` and then ran `systemd-tmpfiles --create --prefix /var/log/journal` without rebooting and it worked.

Comment: My journal service was failing in the same way due to a stray newline in the middle of the `/etc/machine-id` file.  Dunno how that got there!  Removing the file, running `systemd-machine-id-setup` then `systemctl start systemd-journald.service` fixed it.  No reboot necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Try deleting `/var/log/journal` in case that there are any remainders from previous restoring attempts. Then set `Storage=persistent` in `/etc/systemd/journald.conf` and reboot.

Normally systemd should recreate `/var/log/journal` during reboot.

If this doesn't help try

```
mkdir -p /var/log/journal
systemd-tmpfiles --create --prefix /var/log/journal
```

Answer (score -1):

Try: `systemctl stop systemd-journald && strace systemctl start systemd-journald`

That should stream *a lot* of detail about what's going while the process is starting up. The final lines may provide a clue why it continues to fail.

Comment: Then strace will trace only systemctl, not the actual systemd. It uses IPC to communicate with main daemon.